# pyspark dataframe add a column if it doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have json data in various json files And the keys could be different in lines, for eg

```
{"a":1 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3"}
{"a":1 , "b":"abc2", "d":"abc"}
{"a":1 ,"b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3"}
```

I want to aggreagate data on column 'b','c','d' and 'f' which is not present in the given json file but could be present in the other files. SO as column 'f' is not present we can take empty string for that column.

I am reading the input file and aggregating the data like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df =  spark.read.json(inputfile)
df2 =df.groupby("b","c","d","f").agg(f.sum(df["a"]))
```

This is the final output I want

```
{"a":2 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3","f":"" }
{"a":1 , "b":"abc2", "c":"" ,"d":"abc","f":""}
```

Can anyone please Help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check if colum is available in dataframe and modify `df` only if necessary:

```
if 'f' not in df.columns:
   df = df.withColumn('f', f.lit(''))
```

For nested schemas you may need to use `df.schema` like below:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)

>>> 'b' in df.schema['a'].dataType.names
True
>>> 'x' in df.schema['a'].dataType.names
False
```

Comment: Thank you ,it is so simple. I think I need to go through the documentation again.

Comment: @Mariusz I have two dataframes. I compared their schema and one dataframe is missing 3 columns. I have this as a list.

Now I want to add these columns to the dataframe missing these columns. with null values. How can we do that in a single shot.

Comment: @Virureddy for each missing column execute `df = df.withColumn(col_name, lit(None).cast(col_datatype))`

Comment: @Mariusz Can we automate this. I am getting Cannot resolve column exception . And I dont want to hardcode column names as there are 50 something columns for each job.

Comment: sure, but you need to have a valid columns list somewhere (because code needs to know what is your reference schema). Then just add a for loop: `for column in columns_list: if column not in df.columns: ...`

Comment: How this can be used for nested columns? I've tried this for nested columns,  but it didn't worked.

Comment: @sandeep Please use the updated answer for the hint how to test availability of nested columns

Comment: I needed to use the equivalent of `df.schema['a].dataType.elementType.names` on my nested array object. Without `elementType` I was not able to access the list of nested field names.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone needs this in Scala:

```
if (!df.columns.contains("f")) {
  val newDf = df.withColumn("f", lit(""))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function result for me.

```
    def detect_data(column, df, data_type):
          if not column in df.columns:
            ret = lit(None).cast(data_type)
          else:
            ret = col(column).cast(data_type)
            
          return ret

    df = df.withColumn('f', detect_data('f', df, StringType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a spark function which you can use in a `df.transform(f)`:

```scala
def addMissingColumn(
      colName: String,
      defaultColumn: Column = lit(null).cast(StringType)
    ): DataFrame => DataFrame = { df =>
      val noInfoPresent = !df.columns.toSeq.contains(colName)
      val dfUpdated = if (noInfoPresent) {
        df.withColumn(colName, defaultColumn)
      } else { df }

      dfUpdated

    }
```