# How to handle missing columns in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are dealing with schema free JSON data and sometimes the spark jobs are failing as some of the columns we refer in spark SQL are not available for certain hours in the day. During these hours the spark job fails as the column being referred is not available in the data frame. How to handle this scenario? I have tried UDF but we have too many columns missing so can't really check each and every column for availability. I have also tried inferring a schema on a larger data set and applied it on the data frame expecting that missing columns will be filled with null but the schema application fails with weird errors.

Please suggest

Comment: What are your "weird errors".  Setting an explicit schema with all fields should work as you described where missing values are set to NULL.

Comment: @RyanWidmaier But when I add new columns in the schema and apply to a data frame, it fails. I will post the exact error.

Comment: I have the same issue - the Google API returns JSON with 188 columns and sometimes they just don't return a column and other times it does but with nulls or values. I refer to specific columns by name so it fails. I need to put in a check to see if the column exists and if not add it with a default first. I am using PySpark and do not specify the schema, I infer it. I'll try the solution below and also an explicit schema definition

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Created a  function to check all expected columns and add columns to dataframe if it is missing

```
def checkAvailableColumns(df: DataFrame, expectedColumnsInput: List[String]) : DataFrame = {
    expectedColumnsInput.foldLeft(df) {
        (df,column) => {
            if(df.columns.contains(column) == false) {
                df.withColumn(column,lit(null).cast(StringType))
            }
            else (df)
        }
    }
}

val expectedColumns = List("newcol1","newcol2","newcol3")

val finalDf = checkAvailableColumns(castedDateSessions,expectedColumns)
```

Comment: how does this change if u have nested Columns; example column like `a.b.c.e` where `b` and `e` are arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of the answer @rads provided

```
@tailrec
def addMissingFields(fields: List[String])(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

  def addMissingField(field: String)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    df.withColumn(field, lit(null).cast(StringType))

  fields match {
    case Nil =>
      df
    case c :: cs if c.contains(".") && !df.columns.contains(c.split('.')(0)) =>
      val fields = c.split('.')
      // it just supports one level of nested, but it can extend
      val schema = StructType(Array(StructField(fields(1), StringType)))
      addMissingFields(cs)(addMissingField(fields(0), schema)(df))
    case ::(c, cs) if !df.columns.contains(c.split('.')(0)) =>
      addMissingFields(cs)(addMissingField(c)(df))
    case ::(_, cs) =>
      addMissingFields(cs)(df)
  }
}
```

Now you can use it as a transformation:

```
val df = ...
val expectedColumns = List("newcol1","newcol2","newcol3")

df.transform(addMissingFields(expectedColumns))
```

I haven't tested it in production yet to see if there is any performance issue. I doubt it. But if there was any, I'll update my post.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps to add missing columns:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL json example")
  .master("local[1]")
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.json
val schema = df.schema
val columns = df.columns // enough for flat tables
```

You can traverse the auto generated schema. If it is flat table just do 
df.columns.
Compare the found columns to the expected columns and add the missing fields like this:

```
val dataframe2 = df.withColumn("MissingString1", lit(null).cast(StringType) )
  .withColumn("MissingString2", lit(null).cast(StringType) )
  .withColumn("MissingDouble1", lit(0.0).cast(DoubleType) )
```

Maybe there is a faster way to add the missing columns in one operation, instead of one by one, but the with `withColumns()` method which does that is private.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pyspark solution based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527585/193512) which checks for a list of names (from a configDf - transformed into a list of columns it should have - parameterColumnsToKeepList) - this assumes all missing columns are ints but you could look this up in configdDf dynamically too. My default is null but you could also use 0.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

for column in parameterColumnsToKeepList: 
    if column not in processedAllParametersDf.columns:
      print('Json missing column: {0}' .format(column))
      processedAllParametersDf = processedAllParametersDf.withColumn(column, lit(None).cast(IntegerType()))
```