# How to handle missing column in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have 100 csv files which are expected to have A,B,C,D,E columns of String type.

But due to some source issue, 20 of my files have only A,B,D,E columns with C column being missed

Now while reading these csv files to store in dataframe, I want to read in a way that whenever C column is missed, it should be added and filled with null values in pyspark

Comment: Please edit your question to add specifics, including your code. Also, you should do a search on Stack Overflow, as there are other instances of very similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771934/how-to-handle-missing-columns-in-spark-sql).

Comment: Add column `C` if it's not in columns, `if 'C' not in df.columns: df = df.withColumn('C', f.lit(None))` ?