# Using Python fstrings to name columns in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to iterate through a list of column names in pyspark and if they don't exist, I want to create them, fill with null values and give them a name using an fstring.

However, when I try the below code, I get the error `Column is not iterable`. Is there a way to fix this?

```
for column in cols_list:
    if not column in df.columns:
        df= df.withColumn(F.col(f"score_{column}"), F.lit(None))
```

The error in more detail:

```
----> 4         df= df.withColumn(F.col(f"score_{column}"), F.lit(None))

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46             start = time.perf_counter()
     47             try:
---> 48                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49                 logger.log_success(
     50                     module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   3325         if not isinstance(col, Column):
   3326             raise TypeError("col should be Column")
-> 3327         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sparkSession)
```

Edit 2: if I remove `F.col`, it generates the columns but their type becomes `void`

Comment: Why are you adding `score_` to the column name? Shouldn't that be in the `if` condition as well?

Comment: Which line is getting the error? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526489/pyspark-dataframe-add-a-column-if-it-doesnt-exist) your `if` condition should work.

Comment: But you don't need `F.col()`, Just `df.withColumn(f"score_{column}", F.lit(None))`

Comment: If i remove ```F.col()``` the column is declared as ```void```

Comment: The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html) says that the first argument to `withColumn()` must be a string, not `Column`.

Comment: See [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-cast-column-type/) for how to specify the datatype of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First param in `withColumn()` is of type `str`. [See docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html).

```py
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...   [('Krishna', 33, 'mars'), ('Gopi', 34, 'venus')],
...   schema=['name', 'age', 'address']
...   )
>>> 
>>> mandatory_columns = ['name', 'age', 'sex']
>>> current_columns = df.columns
>>> 
>>> for col_name in mandatory_columns:
...   if col_name not in current_columns:
...     print(f'{col_name} not in {current_columns} adding it.')
...     df= df.withColumn(f"_{col_name}", F.lit('bi'))
...   else:
...     print(f'{col_name} already in {current_columns}')
... 
name already in ['name', 'age', 'address']
age already in ['name', 'age', 'address']
sex not in ['name', 'age', 'address'] adding it.
>>>
>>> df.columns
['name', 'age', 'address', '_sex']
>>>
>>> df.show()
+-------+---+-------+----+                                                 
|   name|age|address|_sex|
+-------+---+-------+----+
|Krishna| 33|   mars|  bi|
|   Gopi| 34|  venus|  bi|
+-------+---+-------+----+

>>>
```